Is it really impossible to set a default on a component Input in certain contexts Angular 17
I'm hoping I've missed something but it seems that in the following context, it is not possible to set a default on an @Input:

bindToComponentInputs is set to true in the router module config
Input value is not represented in the URL as a query param
parent component doesn't not pass in the Input value

In this context, neither of these approaches will set the desired default:

@Input() foo: string = 'bar'; // value is overridden with undefined
@Input( { transform: (val: string) => val ?? 'bar' }) foo: string;  // transform method is not called by change detection because parent didn't pass this Input value in

We are in a pickle because we have a lot of Input defaults defined, but we want to turn on bindToComponentInputs.  In doing that though, we have to assume that, if our defaults aren't represented in the URL, they will be undefined.
Please, tell me I'm wrong!

When you use @Input always expect the value
No problem, use a setter
  query!:string //<--define your variable "query"

  @Input('query') set _query(value:string){
    //see that always execute this even you don't indicate query
    console.log(value===undefined)

    this.query=value||'query by defect'
  }

a stackblitz
NOTE: In a "normal" input you can use
@Input() query="query by defect"


thanks for your response however this setter is still not called if 'query' is not passed in as an argument.  Also the "normal" input example does not work when using bindToComponentInputs if 'query' is not a param in the URL.  It will always end up undefined :(

You can also, when declare the variable give a value by defect, but in stackblitz lloks like work (in the stackblitz I use standalone component -I'm not checked if not standalone)
